# Rails - Get Paperclip URL using SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have an ecommerce app. I use paperclip to upload images. In my view pages, I use `@product.image.url(:thumb)` for thumbnails and `@product.image.url` as the zoom images.

If I want to use SQL on my product table and get a list of all urls (thumb and full size) how do I do it? Paperclip stores some image info in the table but the url is not stored so I don't know which field to use.

Comment: What is your paperclip version?

Comment: It feels like you are doing something smelly. Is the SQL you need to execute within your rails app?

Comment: I need the urls to use outside of rails. I am preparing a product feed to upload into shopping sites so need the image url with the product details. They are s3 urls.

Comment: As you say, SQL doesn't store any URL. The method `path` and `url` are completely customizable for each model, so they are dynamic methods. You have to read the code generating it from your configuration, and transform it to SQL operators.

Comment: @Moosa Is it a file you are uploading? Or are the sites consuming a feed?

Comment: @DickieBoy i upload a csv file into google shopping, etc.

Comment: @Moosa can't you just create the file with rails, using rails to get the correct urls with no sql needed?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to construct the URL the same way paperclip does it. This is custom for each project. Your SQL server possibly also needs to do hashing and time conversion.

You can find the related code in `Paperclip::Attachment`, `Paperclip::Interpolations` and probably some module within `Paperclip::Storage`.

I don't have an SQL example but a solution in Ruby which only uses the entity and doesn't rely on Paperclip might look something like this:

```
entity = User.first
entity_plural_name = "users"
attachment_plural_name = "pictures"

storage = "https://myapp.s3.amazonaws.com/"
secret = "somer4nd0mhash"

styles = [:min, :max, :original]
styles.each_with_object({}) do |style, aggregator|
  hash = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new, secret, "#{entity_plural_name}/#{attachment_plural_name}/#{entity.id}/#{style}/#{entity.picture_updated_at.to_i}")
  aggregator[style] = "#{storage}/#{entity_plural_name}/#{style}/#{hash}.jpg"
end
```

Using `paperclip 6.1.0`